# getResourceId finds no ID in custom control

Tags: android, android-controls

I'm trying to create a control (a panel that expands and contracts when a header is clicked), and I found some code online. In the constructor, I have

```
TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyControl);
...
int headerId = array.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyControl_header, -1);
```

The control is being created in a layout file with the following XML:

```
<MyControl
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/drawer"
        header="@+id/header" content="@+id/drawerContent"
        android:layout_below="@id/contentContainer" android:background="#00FF00">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@id/header"
            android:text="This is a header"/>

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@id/drawerContent"
            android:text="@string/sample_text" />
</MyControl>
```

The problem is, `getResourceId()` comes back with -1 (i.e., it can't seem to find the resource set to the attribute).

Any idea why?

EDIT: Forgot to include my attrs.xml file:

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="MyControl">
    <attr name="collapsedHeight" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="header" format="reference" />
    <attr name="content" format="reference" />
    <attr name="animationDuration" format="integer" />
</declare-styleable>
```

EDIT 2: Somehow, I didn't think to check the other attributes--there were a couple of other attributes I had added. I checked their values in the debugger, too, and it looks like they're defaulting, as well. So it's not an issue with `getResourceId`, it's something to do with how I'm getting the attributes in general. I'm new to Android, so can anyone see anything in my attribute processing code?

Comment: What's MyControl_header? I see you are not using it in the MyControl view in the XML.

Comment: Sorry; forgot to add the attrs.xml file.

Comment: Again, I don't see where you are using that custom resource in your layout xml.

Comment: The `<declare-styleable>` element in attrs.xml defines attributes for the MyControl control. The way you specify the identifier for the "header" attribute in code is `MyControl_header`. The symbol is defined when the R class is generated.

Comment: Yes dude, but you are not telling android that MyControl_header has something to do with your MyControl view.

Comment: The association is made in the `<declare-styleable>` element (where it gives the name), I assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. It turns out, the attributes have to be namespaced in the XML; I put

```
<MyControl
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/drawer"
    header="@+id/header" content="@+id/drawerContent"...
```

but it needed to be

```
<MyControl xmlns:myPackage="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.my.package"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/drawer"
    myPackage:header="@+id/header" myPackage:content="@+id/drawerContent"
```

After I added those, it found the values just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the resources in values-> attrs.xml file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyControl">
    <attr name="headerId" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot about that part. I've added it to the OP. I didn't include a header ID as an integer type, I included a header as a reference type.